# Session Management in IBM Worklight

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

How do i manage session in worklight?

1) User should be loggin in and user details will be authenticated using worklight adapter's.

2) User identity will be set and session will be maintained.
Can you please tel where do i increase session timeout in worklight ?
If app is in resume state Whether session will be closed ?
Where the scenarios we can maintain a session ?

Additional doubts:
Whether WL.getID() will be unique for each device ?
if app is uninstalled and reinstalled again will WL.getID() remains same.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get started by reading the [Authentication and Security](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-all-tutorials-7-0/) section of the tutorials on the IBM MobileFirst page. There is lots of information there on how authentication and sessions work. If you have other questions, suggest you separate those out into separate questions.